# How to convert List from column to list of DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame which contains categories, and I want to split the DataFrame using categories as `df_name`:

```
df_name = df['category'].unique()
print(sites)
```

result:

```
['df1' 'df2']
```

after splitting the DataFrame using a loop, I get 2 smaller DataFrames, `df1` and `df2`.

Next, I want to alter the DataFrame. I want to remove column `category` from `df1` and `df2`, using `df_name`, but got an error. After trying for awhile I think the problem is because `df_name` is a list.

How do I convert `df_name` from

```
['df1' 'df2']
```

to

```
[df1 df2]
```

?

Comment: What code did you try and what error did you get?

Comment: Don't bother creating the list`df_name` in the first place, you don't need it, it's only confusing you, and you can't do anything useful with a copy of a list of names. If you want to split the DataFrame using categories, use `df.groupby('category')`. Please [read the quickstart on `groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html) etc.

Comment: okay, thanks for the advice, ill try using groupby

Answer (score 1):

why using loop to filter? you can just use `df[df['column'] == 'df1']` to filter `'df1'` value from a column

then if you want to remove column, you can use `del df['category']`

Comment: well, i didn't really know how many categories are there, probably more than 10 categories and I want to process different category using different method so I need to list what df is created

Comment: `df.keys()` return list of column.
`df['col'].unique` return unique value in a column.
I still don't understand why you want to remove quote from unique result